# Create a Automate script and use another script is echo password

Tags: ssh, unix, passwords, automation, echo

I have created a  fully automated script which uses ssh login to login from one server to another and do some file operation, but the script is not fully automated as it prompts for a password, we do not have sshpass and expect package available in our Unix system and can not install also due to infra reasons.

So I have created another script in which runs in the background and echo "password"

```
#!/bin/bash
Do
echo "password"
echo -e "\r"
sleep 3;
while ( condition is true );
```

Running this script in the background, but my main script is not taking passwords from this way and even if I am pushing enter, it says permission is denied.

```
echo "password" | ssh username@server
```

is also not working.

```
Public-key Authentication is not allowed.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Some ssh programs let you specify a password a `username:password@server` but this will leave potentially sensitive data in your command line history.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use another SSH client such as https://github.com/clarkwang/passh, http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html, etc.

Running another script in background will be useless as it is not connected to your primary process' standard input and output.